# How do I update my branch from my development branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch (Let's call it X branch) that I have been working on that comes from my development branch. There have been quite a few changes in my development branch that are not in my X branch.

How do I get my X branch up-to-date with my development branch again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout x
git merge development  # Merges branch 'development' into branch 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer rebasing (to merge), assuming you are on your X branch:

```
git rebase develop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout X
git rebase -i development
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout X
git merge branchname
```